# Session php, данные забываются

Tags: php, сессия

Данные в сессии забываются. При передаче данных со страницы 1 на страницу 2 получаем `array(2) { ["answer1"]=> string(1) "4" ["answer2"]=> NULL }`, при передаче данных со страницы 2 на страницу 3 `array(2) { ["answer1"]=> NULL ["answer2"]=> string(1) "9" }`, почему данные в сессии могут забываться, ведь изначально они записываются корректно?

Answer (score 3):

Данные в сессии не могут выборочно "забываться".
Если данные пропадают не целиком, а частично, то они **перезаписываются**.